# How can I meta tag properly in a CMS where every page has the same <head> code?

Tags: seo, google, html

I'm helping someone update their website with code similar to this

```
<title>keywords | brand</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type=" "/>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://website.com"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Site Name"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Keyword title"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="url"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta itemprop="name" content="schema name"/>
<meta itemprop="url" content="schema url"/>
<meta name="twitter:title" content="title"/>
<meta name="twitter:url" content="url"/>
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"/>
<meta name="description" content="keywords in desc" />
```

The website CMS is using the same header file on every page, so is it okay if this data just repeats on every page?

Also, will canonical be a problem with the same URL being applied at the header of every page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every single one of those apart from the OG:site_name are page specific, so **yes, it will be a problem.**

Specifically, the `<title>` and the canonical tags. If all of your pages have the same `<title>` element, Google is probably going to show all of your pages in search with the same title (they can choose to use on-page titles instead, but this is rarely the case).

The canonical tag is important if there are variants of your url. For instance:

1. http://website.com
2. https://website.com
3. http://www.website.com
4. https://www.website.com

All of the above are considered to be DIFFERENT by Google. However, unless you have redirects in place, some or all of these can be visible and indexable. The canonical tag is meant to tell Google which version to consider the master, so it can attribute rankings of the other versions to it.

Without a canonical tag that is unique, this problem will spread for every single page on your site and you'll get hit with duplicate content warnings.

Your example is also missing the description meta tag, which will also need to be unique.

```
<meta name="description" content="Your page's description, which is typically a couple sentences." />
```

Google can grab this from crawling your pages, but it's best practice to define this so you can guide Google a bit and let it know what you want users to see on the index page.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any suggestion on how to approach this? My desired outcome is to have properly tagged pages that increase website's SEO as well as give Google the proper page description. Right now pages have descriptions such as "Image 001 Image 002"

Comment: It really depends on the CMS being used. Is it something open source with documentation or is it custom? I'd say you should at least be able to pull the title down (since it's got to be named something in the database, at the very least). If it's custom, you may need to build in additional fields for these meta values.

HTML5 allows you to embed these meta elements wherever you please, so as long as your doctype is `<!DOCTYPE html>` then you could, in theory, just add them to the description / content area for each page (but that would be a last resort).

Comment: Ok, I'll try adding the meta tags in the body with fields that I build. Since I cannot edit the head section.